# Cost of virtual inheritance from an interface

Tags: c++, performance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

This is an attempt to understand the impact of using virtual base class inheritance, especially regarding runtime cost. The situation I have in mind also involves *Interfaces* (or *ABC* s for that).

```
   I----------
 / | \        |
D1 D2 D3      Isub
      |     /
      D3Dec
```

So, we have an Interface `I` and we have different implementations `D1`, `D2`, and `D3`. But now the twist is, there is a special *decorator*, which wraps just some (arbitrary) `I` implementation and then adds an extended feature based on the contract expressed through `I`.

Thus, from a logical or design viewangle, it would be desirable to express that extended ability through a sub-interface `Isub` derived from `I`. Thus any `Isub` automatically also fulfils the `I` contract.

### Question: Performance impact

Now, to implement such in C++, *any* implementation of interface `I` must be done `virtual`, and likewise, `Isub` must inherit `virtual` from `I`, otherwise we'd end up with two `I` subobjects residing in `D3Dec`.

- Does this mean, *every implementation of `I` has to pay the price* in terms of memory layout with tricky virtual base offset adjustments. Correct?
- is the situation different when both `I` and `Isub` are pure virtual, i.e. have no members and only pure virtual functions? Would it then be possible to make that work without virtutal inheritance?
- the tricky point to note is when client code only gets a reference to `Isub`. If clients call the extended functionality, they actually call into the implementation of said functionality within `D3Dec`, and this in turn uses the other `I`-functionality to implement the extended feature, since obviously `D3dec` does not know anything about the concrete `I`-implementation it decorates. Does this necessarily mean we have to use *virtual inheritance*? Or is there any template based trick to get around that but still have an (abstracted) sub-Interface `Isub`?

The obvious alternative is of course to cut the link between `I` and `Isub`, turning it into a trivial mix-in. This works, but is ugly, since `Isub` does not make much sense on its own, independent of `I`. Both even use the same data types on the signatures, etc...

Comment: Are you familiar with diamond inheritance? This is essentially what you have here. I'm not sure this is a duplicate, but multiple questions address this.

Comment: u now, measure.

Comment: @kabanus yeah, the »diamond of death«. The question is about a design tradeoff and/or a way to get past that diamond...

Comment: There are very few applications where a few instructions worth of overhead will make a measurable difference, much less a critical one. I agree with @Cheersandhth.-Alf that if you're that concerned about it you need to measure for yourself.

Comment: I would expect this to be a few nano seconds extra per call. Will that be noticeable?

Comment: Nah, again, this is a design question, not about nanoseconds and microbenchmarks. Conducting a real, non-silly measurement would mean to built it that way and put it into widespread every-day use, which could be months to years until we get a result, if at all possible. But this does not mean that we should happily waste resources all day long.

Comment: *Question is*, is my understanding of the language mechanisms correct? is there a known way or pattern to make that work without virtual inheritance?

Comment: Is it the best solution that `Isub` derived from `I`? What if `Isub` contains a pointer to `I`?

Comment: `D3` and `Isub` seems to be part of the diamond pattern. `D1` and `D2` are not and would thus not need a virtual inheritance. Also, if it takes you months or years to notice any possible difference, why do we care?

Comment: @geza good point. not even a pointer, just another method to get "the `I` "...

Comment: @BoPersson point is, _when_ you are able to _measure_ the impact of a design decision, it is too late. Rather you have to _think_ beforehand to avoid bloatware...

Comment: Don't understand your third bullet. Does `D3Dec` inherit from `Isub` like depicted, or vice versa?

Comment: One last thought: if the overhead of virtual inheritance were too great, it wouldn't have been introduced to the language. C++ has always valued performance over almost everything else. Only the most demanding application is going to find the overhead unacceptable, and even then only if the functions being called are almost trivial.

Comment: There is nothing "deadly" about a diamond.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the diamond inheritance problem entirely by making the interface class a *template parameter* of the concrete class. Then there's no more need for virtual class inheritance.

```
class I { ... };

template<class Ifc>
class D3Impl : public Ifc
{ ... };

typedef D3Impl<I> D3;

class Isub : public I { ... };

class D3Dec : public D3Impl<Isub>
{ ... };
```